# making a input type "file" hidden with button

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, input

I was wondering if this is doable? Google comes up with nothing.

Basically i want to my button to simulate when selected, allowing users to upload files. I've read its possible with labels, but i need to do with a button to do UX/UI

```
<button style="position:fixed;bottom:10px;right:70px" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="file" id="files" visbility="hidden" />
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Currently my button looks like this:
   [image]
to this:

[image]

Comment: You can use the `hidden` attribute instead `visbility="hidden"` like: `<input type="file" id="files" hidden />` (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can actually do it with `label`, you just have to hide the `input`.

```html
<!-- head -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- body -->
<label for="upload">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none">
</label>
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't work on old Android 4.2 browser.

Comment: "for" in the label Tag and "id" in the input Tag have to match. The rest is just for styling.

Comment: Note that Android 4.2 and less represents 0.1% of users

Answer (score 17):

try an opacity of 0

```
opacity:0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m4e0y2o3/12/

plus fallbacks if you what to support older browsers

```css
.hiddenFileInput > input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hiddenFileInput{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /*for the background, optional*/
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 75% 75%;
  background-image:  url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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)
}
```

```html
<span class="hiddenFileInput">
  <input type="file" name="theFile"/>
</span>
```

Comment: get a 404 for that fiddle.

Comment: On hover cursor isn't become as pointer on top ( I guess need to add some offset

Comment: @victor-radu, can you, please, explain the reason for you choosing `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none`. 
A little bit of reasoning (explaining when `opacity: 0` will be better) will be helpful for future reference. Thank you!

Comment: hello, @BorisD.Teoharov display none does not actually render the element in the dom, making interactions with it hardly possible. Opacity 0 renders the element but makes it completely transparent meaning that it will still catch the click interaction as you are clicking on it even if you do not see it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using **Angular** I suppose this pretty solution

```
  <button class="" (click)="uploader.click()">
     <input hidden type="file" #uploader />
  <button>
```

you can easly make the analogy with other techno

Comment: This is a perfect solution when using Angular.

Comment: How about the angular case when button is in the button row above the program and the place to display input image are in separated group i.e.:display section is in sketch.component.html / sketch.component.ts / sketch.component.spec.ts / topnav.component.scss while the button component is in topnav.component.html / topnav.component.ts / topnav.component.spec.ts / topnav.component.scss? Could you show me the example how to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

As all the other answers mention various ways of hiding the `<input>` element, consider using `opacity: 0` as well, as quoted from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file):

> Note: opacity is used to hide the file input instead of visibility: hidden or display: none, because assistive technology interprets the latter two styles to mean the file input isn't interactive.

You can pretty much trigger the file input with any other event (eg: button click, hover, etc.), you can call `click()` on the `input` element (getting it with `getElementById()`, `querySelector()`, etc.)

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById('file-input-element')

// on some other event
inputElement.click() // will let user select files
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do:

```
<button id="fileup" style="position:fixed;bottom:10px;right:70px" type="button" class="btn btn-default" >
<input type="file" id="files" visbility="hidden"/>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<script>
$('#fileup').click(function() {
   $('#files').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you better change the visibility="hidden" to style="display: none"

Comment: To know more about difference, [visibility hidden vs display none](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/4067157).

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
<label htmlFor="inputGroupFile01">
     <span className="fa fa-file-image fa-lg"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `style="opacity: 0"` in the input:

```
<input type="file" id="files"  style="opacity: 0"/>
```

**Opacity versus Visibility:**
`opacity` is used to hide the file input instead of `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`, because assistive technology interprets the latter two styles to mean the file input isn't interactive.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Your Button (with only folder icon):

```html
<button style="position:fixed;bottom:10px;right:70px" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="file" id="files"  style="opacity: 0"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    button
</button>
```

Bona Fortuna!

Answer (score 0):

A nice way of doing this is making the input field to be

- positioned absolute inside parent element
- having zero opacity
- filling the whole parent element

Parent element in this example is a button.

```
<button 
  style="padding: 0.625rem; border-radius: 9999px; background-color: #1F87CC; position: relative;"
>
  <input
    type="file"
    style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; top: -1px; left: 0px; right: 0px; opacity: 0;"
  >
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#FFFFFF" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1rem; height: 1rem;"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.621 4.379a3 3 0 00-4.242 0l-7 7a3 3 0 004.241 4.243h.001l.497-.5a.75.75 0 011.064 1.057l-.498.501-.002.002a4.5 4.5 0 01-6.364-6.364l7-7a4.5 4.5 0 016.368 6.36l-3.455 3.553A2.625 2.625 0 119.52 9.52l3.45-3.451a.75.75 0 111.061 1.06l-3.45 3.451a1.125 1.125 0 001.587 1.595l3.454-3.553a3 3 0 000-4.242z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
</button>
```

Which will result in looking like this. The rounded button is working as an input field of type "file".

[image: result]

Answer (score -1):

Simple Method with beautiful input file [type="file"].

Output Image URL - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jl0H.jpg

```css
input[type="file"] {
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 67px;
 width: 85%;
 z-index: 99;
 margin-top: 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.custom-file-upload {
 position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
 padding-top:40px;
 padding-bottom:40px;
 background:url(http://www.a-yachtcharter.com/search-fleet/webaccess/assets/img/uploadIcon.png) #fff center center no-repeat;
 width:91%;
 border:1px dashed #ff5b57 !important;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:20px;
 margin-top:10px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple class="form-control">
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload"></label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to make an input type "file" hidden with a button:

```
<div>
     <input type="file" id="files" style="display:none"/>
     <button onclick="click_the_button(files);">Click me</button>
</div>enter code here

<script>
    function click_the_button(btn){
        btn.click();
    }
</script>
```